# Familial risk study using case control database?

Tags: logistic, survival, case-control-study

If I have a dataset with cases and controls ( cases being people with colon cancer, control are people without colon cancer), and for each case or control, there are multiple relatives linked to them with their own variables. The rows are duplicated because one person can have multiple relatives. We would like to investigate if having a relative with colon cancer would be a risk factor for colon cancer. The dataset looks like this:
[image]

There are also other demographic variables for case control and relatives. What kind of analysis should we do? Survival analysis or logistic regression? What kind of format should we keep?